# Is the superposition principle universal?

Tags: electromagnetism, superposition

In David J. Griffiths' *Introduction to Electrodynamics*, he claims that the superposition principle is not obvious but has always been found to be consistent with the experiments. So I was wondering have we found some physics quantities which do not follow superposition principle? If we have not till now why can't we generalize and make it into a law?

More specifically: Griffiths was talking about electromagnetic force. My question is about the existence of something like mass or charge and which doesn't follow this superposition principle.

Comment: Could you include a quote - without it, it's hard to guess what Griffiths was talking about - maybe the linearity of Maxwells equations, or the superposition of quantum states...?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are plenty of quantities that do *not* obey the superposition principle. A simple pendulum, for example, will behave differently (with a longer period) if you double the initial amplitude.

What Griffiths means by that quote is that **for the electromagnetic field** there are no situations where the fields fail to add linearly. More specifically, the superposition principle is encoded in the linearity of Maxwell's equations, which states that

> If $(\mathbf{E}_1(\mathbf{r},t),\mathbf{B}_1(\mathbf{r},t))$ and $(\mathbf{E}_2(\mathbf{r},t),\mathbf{B}_2(\mathbf{r},t))$ are solutions of Maxwell's equations, then $$(\mathbf{E}_1(\mathbf{r},t)+\mathbf{E}_2(\mathbf{r},t),\mathbf{B}_1(\mathbf{r},t)+\mathbf{B}_2(\mathbf{r},t))$$ is also a solution.

This is indeed consistent with experiment, except for two situations:

- If the field strength inside a medium exceeds that of its linear response, then the [*material* ("macroscopic") Maxwell equations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell's_equations#.22Microscopic.22_versus_.22macroscopic.22) are no longer a linear problem. This is the bread and butter of [nonlinear optics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonlinear_optics), which describes a broad range of phenomena. However, this is *not* a failure of Griffith's claim, as the 'microscopic' fields $\mathbf{E}$ and $\mathbf{B}$ are still a linear superpositions of those created by the free and bound charges.
- In certain, very careful experiments, it is possible to observe the [scattering of light by light](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/1361/scattering-of-light-by-light-experimental-status). This is explained by [Quantum Electrodynamics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_electrodynamics) as the temporary creation and annihilation of virtual particle-antiparticle pairs where the light beams meet, which transfer energy and information from one beam into the other. This *does* violate the superposition principle as stated above and as meant by Griffiths in his textbook, and it *has* been observed experimentally. However, outside of very specific experiments specially designed to observe it, this effect is negligible and can be ignored as regards classical electrodynamics. In the quantum version, you have a whole host of such problems to deal with.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is that there are "physics quantities" that do not obey a superposition principle.  The energy density of the electric field is proportional to $E^2$ so if $\bf{E}=\bf{E}_1+\bf{E}_2$, the energy density is *not* the sum of the energy densities due to $E_1$ and $E_2$ separately.

Superposition is far from being a universal principle.  Suppose that a physical quantity $f$ depends another physical quantity $x$ and that $f$  obeys a superposition law in $x$ so that $f(x_1+x_2)=f(x_1)+f(x_2)$.  Then I can always define $\bar{x}=x^3$.  Then I can choose to regard $f$ as linear in $x$ or nonlinear in $\bar{x}$.

Perhaps there is some way to phrase what you are really trying to get at with your question that doesn't fall into these obvious loopholes, but my feeling is that it's wrong to think of superposition as being a "universal law".

Answer (score 2):

Superposition principle is normally valid for weak fields. It is implemented in the Maxwell equations that are linear in fields with constant (field-independent) coefficients.

Deviation from linearity occurs for strong fields (non-lienar equations due to field-dependent coefficients). For example, a dielectric breakdown can be described as an essential change in the dielectric conductivity starting from some field value (threshold behavior).

Comment: I think we are speaking of different things. In nonlinear interactions, you are dealing with tensor spaces, which does not change the fact that the abstract field operations do not change.

Comment: Tensor spaces are not obligatory in our case. Imagine that some fields cannot exist due to breakdown they cause. You cannot simply add field strengths. The discharge is a mechanism of decreasing the field.

Answer (score -2):

Any physical quantity that can be organized as a vector space obeys the superposition principle. I would go as far as to say that the superposition principle arises from the fact that a vector space is closed under the weak operation $+$ of the field $\mathbb{(R,+,\cdot)}$.

Comment: :How did u arrive into this conclusion? Is there any example you can show which doesn't obey this principle or any field which is not vector?

Comment: Temperature field is not additive, and pressure field is ;-)

Comment: Nature as we know it can be organized as abstract mathematical objects, such as groups, rings and fields. If this is true, then the conclusion follows directly from the mathematics. For example, the Poincare group plays a central role in describing the fields you speak of. I will revisit this question, for it is a good one and I need a bit of time to organize my thoughts. :)

Comment: However I consider the main Antillar's answer as a tautology.

Comment: Vladmir, what is the specific problem? Please check my comment above and see if it clarifies matters (a bit).

Comment: @AntillarMaximus: A linear space where the "+" operation is an essential part of its definition implies, of course, superposition, but it does not serve as the origin of superposition principle. The "+" operation is a synonym of superposition. Moreover, precisely possibility of adding elements creates a linear space for these elements.

Comment: I have to disagree with that. In fact the closure property of a group is the fundamental principle at play. The principle of superposition is antiquated and anybody who studies group theory will tell you that it is unnecessary terminology. The "+" can be replaced by another operation say $\diamond$. The point is, you have to decide which is the strong and which is the weak operation when you build a field from a group and two operations.

Comment: This is mixing up math and physics.  We often model a physical system via a vector space because of some superposition principle.  The answer basically says that "superposition holds whenever superposition holds".

Comment: in special relativity velocities are vectors but do not add vectorially. something being a vector is not an excuse to declare that any composition of two such vectors must be addition. we model displacement as a vector and it follows that velocity, acceleration and force etc. are vectors. But Galilean relativity doesnt follow from this.