# Photons interact with themselves

Tags: photons, quantum-electrodynamics

We know that photons are the antiparticles of themselves and if they interact with each other through higher order process do they annihilate and again produce photons?

[Here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/54323/2451) is the Phys.SE question that made me ask this question.

Comment: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/54323/collision-of-two-photons here is the link which made me to ask this question and i didnt found what i searched for?

Comment: have a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-photon_physics for photon photon interactions in general

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/1361/2451 and links therein.