# Why don't photons crash into each other occasionally? Or do they?

Tags: photons, large-hadron-collider

At the LHC, researchers smash particles into each other at speeds close to speed of light. Photons, on the other hand, already move at the speed of light. Do they ever smash into each other? Or do they just go through each other? Why?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Collision of two photons](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/54323/)

Comment: I think the answers in the duplicate are sufficient.

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/1361/2451 and links therein.